# Print dependency tree for project

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I know how to dump dependency tree for package:

```bash
swift package show-dependencies
```

But for project?

Comment: In `project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved`, there is the `.resolved` file, but no `Package.swift`. Might still be of help maybe?

Comment: `Package.resolved` contains plain dependency list, unfortunately, not a tree.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/tracing-dependencies-and-generating-dependency-graphs/51099/10
related, without answer tho :/ any update since? @bteapot

Comment: nothing so far, though I made a hacky swift script to do just this, I'm still searching for a proper clean tool doing it :(

Answer (score 1):

Not a beautfiful solution and I just finished it (no longer testing) but it works so far for Xcode 14.1:

- Create a `Scripts/dependenciesTree.sh` bash-script under your project root:

```bash
if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
  echo "Missing build dir as 1st parameter"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $2 == "" ]]; then
  echo "Missing project dir as 2nd parameter"
  exit 1
fi

BUILD_DIR=$1
PROJECT_DIR=$2

echo "Build dependencies tree"
cd "$BUILD_DIR/../../SourcePackages/checkouts"
exportFile="$PROJECT_DIR/dependencies-tree.md"
echo "# Dependencies trees for each Swift-Package" > "$exportFile"
echo "" >> "$exportFile"
echo "Build date: $(date '+%Y-%d-%m %a %H:%M:%S %Z')" >> "$exportFile"
echo "" >> "$exportFile"
for directory in */; do
  echo "Tree for $directory"
  echo "" >> "$exportFile"
  echo "## Tree for $directory" >> "$exportFile"
  pushd $directory
  swift package show-dependencies >> "$exportFile"
  echo "" >> "$exportFile"
  echo "" >> "$exportFile"
  popd
done
```

- Go to your Project configuration, Targets, "Build Phases" and add a "New Run Script Phase". In the script add this lines:

```bash
# Script must be run without Xcode environment variables,
# otherwise it may try to build an iOS application targeting macOS based on iOS.
# Which doesn't make any sense and always fails.
env -i "$PROJECT_DIR/Scripts/dependenciesTree.sh" "$BUILD_DIR" "$PROJECT_DIR"
```

The result is then in the `dependencies-tree.md` file.

Although, this has one problem: If a package is added from a local directory, not a GIT repository, it won't be listed there. But its transitive dependencies should be listed there, if they reference a GIT repository.

Comment: Unfortunately this script did not produce a graph. It just produces the following error: ```error: Could not find Package.swift in this directory or any of its parent directories.```